# HTML CSS Zoom in / Zoom Out issue

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

when zooming in and out my page [Link of my page](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/) in Chrome browser the background is distorted and page looks like this [Look of page after zooming in Chrome](http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/g6qaizz5_png.htm).
What can be changed in code to fix it for zooming in Chrome browser without distorting background graphic?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Under Construction</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">

body {
background:#d7df29 url('1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height:  100%;
}

html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
    }


</style>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your link sends to an 'under construction' message. The problem here isn't clear.

Comment: http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/g6qaizz5_png.htm is it a working link? I cant find it

Comment: The under construction message is my page at the moment. When zooming in Chrome it is distorting the message like in the images I posted. That is the problem. Need to be fixed so that when zooming in and out the message is not distorted.

Comment: yes the link http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3168/g6qaizz5_png.htm should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line says, **WE CANT HELP YOU YET...**

```
background:#d7df29 url('1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
```

I just read you comment, you got an image, so it will be distoring with zoom in / zoom out...it would be better to go for CSS to avoid such distorting...

Comment: can you tell me how it could be made? because I have no idea and I'm not so advanced in HTML CSS

Comment: try google and search for "css create under construction page"

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/faq and if my answer helps you solve your issue, you can accept :P